# How to avoid shrink UIWebView when keyboard hide in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova, uiwebview, phonegap-plugins

I make application phonegap in iOS, but I got issue that uiwebview shrink when keyboard hide.
So that header and footer move another position. I cannot resolve this problem. Someone can help me?
You can see some screen here:
Focus input text:
[image: img1]
Keyboard display:
[image: img2]

And when I click on the "Mua" button. Keyboard hide, but webview resize like in image.
[image: img3]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your base Divs are Absolute rather than fixed